# I can't tell if an answer to my old question is correct

Tags: discussion, old-questions

More than two years ago, I've made [this programming question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13710363/641451). I was struggling with that at work, and didn't know what to do.

Yesterday, it got [a new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30203509/641451).

I don't work in that company anymore, nor have the code/environment set up to test if what the user says is OK or not. I don't even remember the problem anymore - I can't tell if I've solved that or it was left undone.

Is there something I should do about that question or its answers?

I don't want the users to feel I don't care about the effort they do for answering, but I don't want to upvote anything I haven't tested at all, too. I can't even guess if the answer makes sense or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there something I should do about that question or its answers?

Yes, nothing.

You certainly shouldn't vote on a post when you don't know if it's a quality answer.

If you want to comment explaining that you're no longer in a position to evaluate the quality of the answer, you certainly can; it wouldn't be wrong to do so, but it's also not required.

Other readers of the post can vote on the answer's quality, if they feel confident that they can evaluate it.