# How to deal with answers to questions that I have given up on?

Tags: discussion

What should I do when someone answers one of my questions that I have "given up on" (e.g. a project that I have put on the back burner, or an issue that I can't reproduce, because I no longer have access to the code [internship])?

If other people upvote the answer or confirm that it is correct, should I go ahead and mark it as best answer even though I haven't implemented the solution?

Comment: Closely related: [I can't tell if an answer to my old question is correct](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256460)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you aren't able to properly evaluate the answer and determine how good it is, then you should do nothing.  You shouldn't vote on the answer either up or down, nor should you accept it.  The community will be able to vote and, as a result, indicate to other readers what they feel the quality of each answer is.

If you *are* capable of evaluating the quality of the answer, even though you no longer *need* the answer, and are confident that you can provide an accurate indication of the quality of the answer, then feel free to cast a vote accordingly.  If there is an answer that you're confident is correct, that answers your question, and that you feel is the best answer, then you can choose to accept it.